# How to detect that you've been re-directed with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Is there a particular header or environment variable that a request will have set, when it has been redirected by mod_rewrite? I want to put a friendly note to users to update their bookmarks when they're viewing a re-directed resource.

Comment: What do your rules look like? You could tag a query string on the end of redirects or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up about the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header.  If you're using mod_proxy in conjunction with mod_rewrite, (i.e., [your rewrite rule has the "P" flag to force proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)), this header should be appended to your requests.